# Can I call mysql query result into a html file using node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have an question that there is a way to put mysql query results into a html file without template engines or express.

From many examples, they use template engines to contain a mysql result in html 
like this. (using express)

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows){
res.render('users', {users : rows});
```

But I don't want to use template engines.

Is there a way to show mysql query results without using template engines?

Do I have to use squelize or backbone.js?

Thanks.

Comment: what do you want instead of html? May be you want <pre>mysqloutputhere</pre>  If you want console-like output you probably need to connect to mysql via sockets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always Handle the errors. You can directly send the data without using any template engine as shown below.

```
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM users', function(err, rows){
        if(err)
            res.status(500).json({"Error":err});
        else if(rows.length)
            res.status(200).json({"Data":rows});
        else
            res.status(200).json({"Data":"No records found"});
    }
}
```